# On an IMAP request, is there a way to determine the mail server?

Tags: tcp, imap

We're writing a program similar to an anti-virus that sits between an email client and server passing IMAP requests back and forth (and scanning some).

Is there a way on IMAP requests to determine which email domain the request is for? We would prefer to have a single named server all companies that use us hit.

If not, can we create a CNAME record that points to the same server, but then due to the CNAME pull out the name of the server it is connecting to?

thanks - dave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We're writing a program similar to an anti-virus that sits between an email client and server passing IMAP requests back and forth (and scanning some).

Have fun. Especially with partial requests where the mail client only accesses a specific byte range (thunderbird does this for larger mails).  Or have fun with fragments like BODY[1] where you get only the body without the MIME header and thus don't know if this is content-transfer-encoding base64 or whatever (not uncommon with apple mail).

> Is there a way on IMAP requests to determine which email domain the request is for? We would prefer to have a single named server all companies that use us hit.

With IMAP you make a TCP connection to a server and within the IMAP protocol the server name is not shown. The server name is also of no importance for the protocol itself, that is it will work the same if the server does not have a host name but only an IP address.

Server name is only relevant if you do IMAPs or IMAP with STARTTLS because you need some name to verify the name in the certificate. And while HTTP has the Host header to distinguish multiple Servers on the same IP there is no such thing with IMAP. Here you can only distinguish by the user name used for login.

Comment: If we do a unique server name for each, can we pull from the TCP create session the name of the server it is connecting to? ps - Any other lovely little problems we'll see in the requests?

Comment: From TCP you don't get any information about the host name. You might try a DNS reverse lookup, but this does not help if there are multiple names for a single IP. And I wonder why you need the name, because it is not needed for the IMAP protocol itself. As for lovely problems - look at the limits described by Juniper http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/junos12.1/topics/concept/utm-antivirus-full-application-protocol-scan-imap-understanding.html#scan-imap-limitations

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here. If we have this service that multiple companies can use, then when they make a request from their email client, we need to know what mail server to forward that request on to. For example, if we provide this service to Acme Inc. and to IBM, when an email client connects asking for email for the user dave, which do we forward on to? ps - Thank you for the link.

Comment: If multiple companies use the same server with same IP and port you can only distinguish them by the user name they use for login on the IMAP server. While in HTTP you have the Host header to distinguish different servers on the same IP there is no such thing with IMAP.

Comment: Thank you very much. Not the answer I wanted to hear, but it is what it is and knowing the limitations, we now have to figure out what to do.